# Using visjs timeline, how to get start time (where I drop it) of a range item dropped in timeline

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

vijs timeline documentation: https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/

I,m using this example:
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/drag_drop.html

I want to drop an range item on the timeline and set the start time where I drop it and the end time an hour later.

I got end time, no problem.

I´m using this code

```
function handleDragStart(event) {
var dragSrcEl = event.target;
event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
var item = {
        id: new Date(),
        type: 'range',
        content: event.target.innerHTML.trim()
    };
item.start = new Date();
item.end = new Date(1000*60*60 + (new Date()).valueOf());
event.dataTransfer.setData("text", JSON.stringify(item));
```

}

If you see in: item.start = new Date();
I get actual time, not time where I drop item.

I see that I can get time where I drop using:

```
timeline.on('drop', function (properties) {
console.log(properties.time);
```

});

But I cant use it in the function.

Answer (score 1):

At first this was a struggling thing, but i managed to solve it. The following might help future readers:

`vis-timeline` version used **7.4.2**

**Step 1: Define Listeners**

REMEMBER: The `dragend` listener is important to create accurate end time of the item

```
    $('.media_elm').each(function (index, item) {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart.bind(this), false);
        item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd.bind(this), false); // ***
    });
```

**Step 2: Create DragStart Function**

```
function handleDragStart(event) {
    // Get element from event
    let element = event.target;

    // Create item
    let item = {
        id: element.id, // You should define id on the drag element(important)
        content: 'Element',
        type: 'range'
        // IMPORTANT
        // No need to define start or end time here
        // As the accurate start time automatically gets created after dropping the element on the timeline
    }

    // Add item to timeline
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

**Step 3: Create DragEndFunction**

```
function handleDragEnd(e) {
    let element = e.target; // This is the same element as we used before
    
    // Get item data
    let itemData = prevTimeline.itemSet.items[element.id].data; // Here element id is the one which we used to create item

    // Set end time based on the start time and duration
    // This will add 5 seconds to the start time(the time where the item was dropped)
    // You can also define the duration on the drag element and then use it here
    itemData.end = moment(itemData.start).add('5', 's');

    // Update timeline data (auto refreshes)
    prevTimeline.itemsData.update(itemData);
}
```